# Replacing None with 0 in R

Tags: r

So I have data that has None interspersed in numeric vectors, like this -

```
Lot.Frontage    Lot.Area
34                  3901
70                  8400
60                  7200
64                  7018
111                 16259
50                  4280
155                 20064
60                  7200
70                  9100
None            6449
55                  7642
None            28698
```

I want to replace the None with 0.

I've tried this

```
ames.data[ames.data == "None"] <- 0
```

But this gives me an < NA > wherever there was a none.

How do I replace the None with 0?

Comment: `ames.data$Lot.Frontage[ames.data$Lot.Frontage == "None"] <- 0` ? If `ames.data` were a matrix, you would be fine, but I guess it's a data.frame.

Comment: so what I posted above is a subset of the data - I have a lot more columns like that. Doing ames.data[ames.data == "None"] <- 0 has the same issue as in the problem

Comment: Please provide `dput(ames.data)` or otherwise create reproducible data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: The `<NA>` is because `class(ames.data$Lot.Frontage)` is a `factor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do it over all columns. I generated some `"None"`s in `Lot.Area` to show

```
sapply(ames.data, class)
## Lot.Frontage     Lot.Area                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
##     "factor"    "integer"                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

ames.data$Lot.Area <- ifelse(runif(nrow(ames.data)) < 0.25, "None", ames.data$Lot.Area)
##    Lot.Frontage Lot.Area                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 1            34     3901                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 2            70     None                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 3            60     None                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 4            64     7018                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 5           111    16259                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 6            50     4280                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 7           155     None                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 8            60     None                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 9            70     9100                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 10         None     None                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 11           55     7642                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 12         None    28698                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

ames.data <- as.data.frame(lapply(ames.data, function(x) {
  x <- as.character(x)
  x[x == "None"] <- 0
  as.numeric(x)
}))
##    Lot.Frontage Lot.Area                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 1            34     3901                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 2            70        0                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 3            60        0                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 4            64     7018                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 5           111    16259                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 6            50     4280                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 7           155        0                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 8            60        0                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 9            70     9100                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 10            0        0                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 11           55     7642                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 12            0    28698                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

sapply(ames.data, class)
## Lot.Frontage     Lot.Area                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
##    "numeric"    "numeric"
```

Answer (score 1):

Check `class(ames.data$Lot.Frontage)`.  I bet it is a factor.  That means you can only replace values by other values in `levels(ames.data$Lot.Frontage)`.

You can do this a couple of ways, but they all boil down to converting the columns to a type you can change.  In this case, convert to character first, then change "None" to "0", then convert to numeric.

```
ames.data$Lot.Frontage <- as.character(ames.data$Lot.Frontage)
ames.data$Lot.Frontage[ames.data$Lot.Frontage == "None"] <- "0"
ames.data$Lot.Frontage <- as.numeric(ames.data$Lot.Frontage)
```

If you convert directly to numeric, the "None"s will become `NA`s.  Since you may have other missing data, the "None"s and the other missing data will get confused.

Comment: ah that was it - is there a way to do this over all of the columns?

Comment: `lapply(ames.dat, function(col) { col<-as.character(col); col[col == "None"] <- "0"; col})` ... untested.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the data specifying `na.strings="None"` and `colClasses=c("numeric","numeric")` you can replace the "None" with 0 as usual

```
read.table("file", header=T, quote="\"",colClasses=c("numeric","numeric"),na.strings="None")
df[is.na(df)]<-0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr, you can generalize this function `across all columns` that are of `character` type. This is particularly useful when working with a time series, where you have `date` column.

```
library(dplyr)

ames.data <- ames.data %>% 
        mutate(across(where(is.character), ~na_if(., "None"))) %>% 
        mutate(across(where(is.character), as.double))
```

| date | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| {date} | {chr} | {chr} |
| 2000-01-01 | 1 | 2 |
| 2000-01-02 | 4 | None |
| 2000-01-03 | None | 6 |
| 2000-01-04 | 3 | 0 |

will become:

| date | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| {date} | {dbl} | {dbl} |
| 2000-01-01 | 1 | 2 |
| 2000-01-02 | 4 | NA |
| 2000-01-03 | NA | 6 |
| 2000-01-04 | 3 | 0 |